# Using internal RTCC of PIC18F26J50

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, rtc

I'm trying to get the internal RTCC working but it doesn't seem to work.

What I'm using-

- MikroC pro for PIC
- using internal 8mhz clock(INTOSCPLL)
- Using INTRC as a clock source for RTCC

and using the following code:

```
 void main() {

 char txt[7];

 //Setup RTC
 T1CON.T1OSCEN = 1;
 delay_ms(50);
 RTCCFG.RTCWREN = 1;
 PADCFG1.RTSECSEL1 = 1;
 PADCFG1.RTSECSEL0 = 0;
 RTCCFG.RTCEN = 1;
 RTCCFG.RTCPTR1 = 0;
 RTCCFG.RTCPTR0 = 0;

 //Set analog ports as Digital
 ANCON0 = 0x1F;
 ANCON1 = 0x1F;

 I2C1_Init(400000);
 Oled_Init();
 Oled_FillScreen(0x00);

 while(1){
    IntToStr(RTCVALH, txt);
    Oled_Text(txt,0,2);
    IntToStr(RTCVALL, txt);
    Oled_Text(txt,0,4);
    delay_mS(1000);
 }
}
```

The RTCVALH and RTCVALL should display minutes and seconds. But their values don't change at all. They show constant values of 56 and 50.

What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set **RTCCFG.RTCWREN = 0;** after you have finished writing to it. The datasheet mentions it under section **17.2.7 WRITE LOCK**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your configuration bits for setting the RTC clocking source are correct. The bits responsible for is the RTCOSC bit in the the  CONFIG3L.

EDIT: RTCWREN can't simply be set to one. You should follow the sequence mentioned in the datasheet

Comment: Thanks for you answer but if you read the question properly, you'll notice that I've mentioned *Using INTRC as a clock source for RTCC* which is set on CONFIG3L.

Comment: Please check the editted answer